# Expired token when valid a form Laravel

Tags: laravel, token, csrf

I'm stuck for a while on this subject, I've searched the internet but unfortunately I can't find anything.

I have a controller that sends a recipe to my database but when I click on the previous icon of Google, it re-displays me the data entered previously are again displayed. Except that I have implemented csrf and from what I understood it allowed not to return to the form that has already been sent.

No sensitive information gets through but that's mostly because I don't like the user to be able to review his previously sent data...

Here is my controller

```
function index(){
        return view('recette');
    }

    function saveRecette(Request $req){
        $req->validate(
            [
                'nomRecette'=>'required',
                'nbrPersonnes'=>'required|regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
                'facilite'=>'required',
                'detail'=>'required',
                'ingredientPrincipal' => 'required',
            ],
            [
                'required'=>  'Ce champ est obligatoire',
                'nbrPersonnes.regex' => 'Le champ doit contenir que des nombres'
            ]
        );
        $idRecette = Str::uuid();
        $recette = new Recette;
        $recette->id = $idRecette;
        $recette->nomRecette = $req->nomRecette;
        $recette->nbrPersonnes = $req->nbrPersonnes;
        $recette->facilite = $req->facilite;
        $recette->detail = $req->detail;
        $recette->created_at = now();
        $recette->updated_at = now();
        $recetteSave =$recette->save();
        if($recetteSave){
            $listIngredient = $this->getIngredient($req->all());
            foreach($listIngredient as $ingredient){
                $ingred = new Ingredient;
                $ingred->id = Str::uuid();
                $ingred->ingredient = $ingredient;
                $ingred->idRecette = $idRecette;
                if($ingred->save()){
                   
                }
            }
            return redirect('');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('bug', "Un problème est survenue. Veuillez réessayer plus tard");
    }

    function getIngredient($list){
        $listIngredient = [];
        $i=0;
        foreach($list as $ingredient => $de){
            if(strpos($ingredient, 'ingredient') !== false){
                $listIngredient[$i] = $de;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $listIngredient;
    }
```

Here is my Model

```
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table='creationRecette';
    public $incrementing = false;
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'nomRecette',
        'nbrRecettes',
        'facilite',
        'detail'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. CSRF token are to prevent Cross Site Request Forging, not to prevent returns to previous page. For that you will need to make the page expire right after it is shown.

Comment: could be happen some validation or session is emitted and you don't have this implemented in the blade for show the status??? or the validation message??? could you post your blade code?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I would like to expired the page after it show page after the validation